# How to access table column values in react

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have create table and inserted values. Now I need to access some of table data and assign into variable for calculation. here I need to calculate total of those column values and assign to label. So may I know the way ??

This is the table I have created.

```
  render(){
      return (
            <tr>
                <td data-th="Product">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-sm">
                            <h4 className="nomargin">{this.DrugsDetailsRequest.item_name}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td data-th="Price"> Rs: {this.DrugsDetailsRequest.totalPrice}</td>
                <td data-th="Quantity">
                    <input name="textInputValue1" type="number" className="form-control text-center"  onChange={ this.handleChange } />
                </td>
                <td data-th="Subtotal" className="text-center"> <input name="textInputValue2" type="number" className="form-control text-center"  onChange={ this.handleChange } value={this.DrugsDetailsRequest.totalPrice*this.state.textInputValue1}/></td>
                <td className="actions" data-th="">
                    <button className="btn btn-info btn-sm mr-3" onClick={ this.publish }><i className="fa fa-refresh"></i>Refresh</button>
                    <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onClick={(e) => this.delete(this.DrugsDetailsRequest._id)}><i className="fa fa-trash-o">Delete</i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>

    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn’t clear but this is what I understand

A simple solution is. Do this in render before return

```
const total = this.DrugsDetailsRequest.totalPrice + this.DrugsDetailsRequest.totalPrice*this.state.textInputValue1
 console.log(total);// this will get you the total
```

Comment: @Krishan glad to see my fix worked for you. You should also upvote when you accept the answer. Thanks